# Input text from href click

Tags: javascript, input, href

I tried to create something like a "virtual" keypad for entering some special characters in a textbox. The following implementation works OK in Chrome but not in any other browser.

How can this be modified to work in the majority of browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) and also have it support caret position in the case where I need to have more than one input fields?

The code as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.key {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1">

Text: <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
<br>

<a href="javascript:document.form1.field1.value=document.form1.field1.value+'&#198;';return false;" class="key">&#198;</a> 

<a href="javascript:document.form1.field1.value=document.form1.field1.value+'&#248;';return false;" class="key">&#248;</a> 


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I also have tried changing this

```
<a href="javascript:document.form1.field1.value=document.form1.field1.value+'&#198;';return false;" class="key">&#198;</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms("form1").field1.value=document.forms("form1").field1.value+'&#198;';return false;" class="key">&#198;</a>
```

Comment: Check your error log. 

And also, you should not do it this way. You should have your javascript completely separated from your html -- you see how you are repeating your code? 

You would be better off setting a click function on `.key` that adds the text content of the element to your form -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this, I attached event handlers. I recommend JQuery .on() or .click() events. Also try not to do inline JS, its very bad practice.

```
var Key248Btn = document.getElementById('Key248Btn');
Key248Btn.addEventListener("click", Key248_Click, false);

function Key198_Click()
{
    textEntryField.value += "\u00e6";
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HGDZ3/3/

Comment: Thank, that works! Is there a way to not have it binded to a specific input, but change depending on which other input I had my cursor? I assume handling the `focus` won't work because the focus will change once I click the link.

Comment: Here now it binds to all elements with the class ".key" and automatically grabs the data-key-value and adds it to the textbox http://jsfiddle.net/Lord_Zero/HGDZ3/8/ all you have to do is add more <a></a> tags :)

Comment: Awesome work there :) the thing is that I am not working with `textarea` but with separate textboxes. Will setting the `.key` class on all the textboxes, grand me the ability to focus on which textbox I want the text to be entered in?

Comment: Basically, you want to copy/paste my code. Just gather up all the textboxes, loop through them and add a focus event to each one. The focus events will all call the same function which takes in it the element that was clicked and sets a global variable called lastclicked which you then target with your other function. http://jsfiddle.net/Lord_Zero/HGDZ3/17/